# a function for creating shortname style variables in PHP

Tags: php, function, syntax

I'm just learning PHP, and I'm sure I'm not the first person to try something like this, but maybe because I didn't know what to call it, I couldn't find any other examples or questions on here or from a search on google.

I wanted to create a function which takes two parameters and uses them to create all the short style variables I'll be using later in my script.

My problem is where normally the syntax to create a short variable is something like:

```
    $var = $_METHOD['var'];
```

but I'm trying to do this using variables and don't know how to get the syntax right. Here's my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

function shortnames($some_vars, $type) {
    for ($i = 0; $i<(count($some_vars)); $i++) {
        $$some_vars[$i] = $_$type['$some_vars[$i]'];
        echo $$some_vars[$i].' = '.$some_vars[$i].'<br />';  
    }
}

$post_vars = array(lastname,firstname,payment);
$session_vars = array(sessiontxt,province,city,venue,regfee);

shortnames($session_vars,session);
shortnames($post_vars,post);
?>
```

Thanks for helping a beginner!!

Comment: Ahhh Variable Variables.... DONT!

Comment: Please don't do something like this. It will make your scripts difficult to debug down the road, and possibly open you up to security issues.

Comment: If you want to keep on that road, look at [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) .Anyway, use quotes with strings: `array('lastname', 'firstname', 'payment');`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Not the answer I was looking for, but maybe the one I should listen to. I went with a different approach.

Comment: @DamienPirsy Thanks for the tips, I will look into extract, I'm not sure how to use it.